# PHP preg_match_all : find string with "@word" or "#word" in it

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Let me clear the logic I wanted to achieve.

1. I have many comments and topic words in DB
2. I want to match topic word in comment via regular express.
3. Match words will be queried on DB and get their topicid and apply topic for comment for tag cloud generation purpose.

but any how words starting with "**@**" and "**#**" do not getting work in preg_match_all pattern for eg.

```
$pattern = '/\b(\@abdulcollo|tuskys|\#teamBata|50\% off|baby|\@mystic_false)\b/i';

$string = 'Anga lonely everyday RT @Mystic_False: Heehe @AbdulCollo aneno ka idhi tuskys in lonely woman bana #TeamBata in Kakamega baby! @danaceda @kibalimoreithi @olivermathenge @batakenya @ Tuskys Mega Mall 50% off';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

var_dump($matched) return below array.

```
$matches = array('tuskys', 'baby', '50% off');
```

but I also wanted to have *'@abdulcollo'*, *'#TeamBata'*, *'@Mystic_False'*, I had escaped "@" and "#" but still they are not getting matched...!

Any help much appreciated, I want logic for Pure PHP.

***NOTE*** : I lowercase everything for eg, lower case words when creating pattern for tag word and also lower whole comment string, so this is not any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the word boundary `\b`. There isn't a word boundary exists between non-word character and a non-word character. So change your regex to,

```
(\B@abdulcollo|\btuskys|\B#teamBata|\b50\% off|\bbaby|\B@mystic_false)\b
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash it is working another fix is I just removed **\b** from my regular expression `(@abdulcollo|tuskys|#teamBata|50% off|baby|@mystic_false)` and it is working fine now.